# Sticky Element Inside non-scrollable element

Tags: html, css

I Have a Button inside a section that must be as fixed position inside it on page scrolling - and the section itself is not scrollable and can have different heights, how can do to create the '`a.button-primary`' to be fixed inside the parent ('`.container`') on page scrolling?

```
<body>
<header class="section page-header">
</header>
<section class="breadcrumbs-custom-inset">
</section>
<section class="section section-sm bg-default">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="button-primary button" href="">
            <span class="icon fa fa-plus"></span>
            Add New Item
        </a>
        <div class="row-sm row-40 row-md-50 justify-content-center">
        <!--List of Items-->
        </div>
  </div>
</section>
</body>
```

I tried Sticky Position - it didn't work correctly
also tried fixed position - it fixed the button according to window not .container

That is the simple css i used

```
.container{
position: relative
}

.button{
position:sticky;
top: 0;
right: 0;
}
```

this works when I add a `Height: 100px; overflow-y: scroll` to `.container` but I dont need to add height for it

Comment: You need to provide the CSS you've used too.

Comment: @learningtoanimate I added

Comment: Is your question answered?

Answer (score 0):

To used a different ancestor than the `body` as a point to relate `position: fixed` to, apply a zero-transformation to the desired ancestor:

```
.container { transform: translate(0); }
```

This most likely **will not achieve the desired result** if `.container` itself scrolls out of the viewport.

> `fixed`
> The element is removed from the normal document flow, and no space is created for the element in the page layout. It is positioned relative to the initial containing block established by the viewport, **except when one of its ancestors has a transform, perspective, or filter property set to something other than `none`** (see the CSS Transforms Spec), **in which case that ancestor behaves as the containing block.**

Source: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#syntax)